# Using the Progressive Form of Be for a State of the Mind and Lately in Present Continuous

Tags: grammaticality, perfect-aspect, progressive-aspect, copular-verbs

Firstly, is the following sentence correct?

> My brother is being unusually nervous lately.

If correct, how is *being nervous* behavior? We usually use the progressive of *be* to describe a behavior or an action, not states of the mind.

Secondly, I have read in both Longman and the Oxford dictionary that you use *only* present perfect with *lately*.

Comment: Please define “correct”. Certainly it is a perfectly unremarkable utterance by native speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Possibility. It seems to me that the adjectives that describe some character can denote behavior in this structure (being + adjective), not those which describe states.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is incorrect. The correct verb tense is present perfect - ‘has been...lately’.

> My brother *has been* unusually nervous *lately*.

The present form of this sentence would be:

> My brother is unusually nervous today.

‘Nervous’ is an adjective that describes a state of mind, not a behaviour. Although people do try to use ‘being nervous’ to describe someone’s behaviour, it always implies the state of mind.

Comment: I agree with you!